# C text alignment with padding

Tags: c, padding

I have a simple function to print text.

```
while (recvbuf[i] != '\0') {
    if (i == 0) {
        printf("%+40c", recvbuf[i]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%c", recvbuf[i]);
    }
    i++;
};
```

It prints text and first word(line) starts with padding 40. But what I want to do is to start every line of this with padding 40 not only first. Don't know how to do it.

Thanks for any help.

What i need as output in CONSOLE.

```
             fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
             fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
             fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
             fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
             fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
             fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
             fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
```

What i have now.

```
             fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
```

Comment: Err... remove the condition then? Did you write any code of this yourself or did you even try to understand what's happening?

Comment: How about a complete and compile able example?

Comment: But when i remove IF statement i get every WORD with padding 40 while i need every new LINE with padding 40 :/

Comment: your while loop ends after the first line because the condition is `!= 'n'`... or what is a line for you?

Comment: No i receive long meesage. And at the end of this message is "\n" So i get entire meesage from server but every NEW LINE starts with padding 0. Only first starts with padding 40.

Comment: Did you mean that you need to split a long message on several lines??

Comment: Well theoretically yes. U can check example what i added.

Comment: You did not initialize your i value.

Comment: I have it earlier in code. int i = 0;

Comment: The `+` in the format is ignored. It has no meaning with `%c`.   What’s wrong with `if (I == 0 || recvbuf[i-1] == ‘\n’) …indent…`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's padding you want (for me, padding comes after, so I won't use this terme). You want to add some space formatting at starting of console line.

So you must define: the console width, the starting spaces you want.

Then, for each word to print, you must calculate if the console width well be reach.
If so, you must start a new line.

If a new line is needed, you must start it with spaces.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int word_length(const char *word)
{
    int size = 0;
    for (; *word && !isspace(*word); ++word)   
{     
        ++size;
    }
    return size;
}

void print_word(const char *word, int size)
{
    while(size--)
        putchar(*word++);

    putchar(' ');

}

void format(int width, int spaces, const char *text)
{
    int sol = spaces;
    int current_pos = 0;

    while (*text)
    {   
        /* size of the current word */
        int word_len;

    /* if needed, print spaces */
        for (; sol != 0; --sol)
        {
            putchar(' ');
            ++current_pos;
        }

        /* get size of next word */
        word_len = word_length(text);

        if (word_len > width)
        {
            printf("error, word too long...\n");
            return;
        }


    /* see if writting current word will go over width*/
        if (current_pos + word_len > width)
        {
            sol = spaces;
            current_pos = 0;
            putchar('\n');
            continue;
        }

        /* print the current word */
        print_word(text, word_len);

        /* update the cursor position */
        current_pos += word_len + 1;

        /* position text pointer position on next word */
        text += word_len;            
        while(*text && isspace(*text))
        {
            ++text;
        }                        
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char text[] = "fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd";
    format(45, 5, text);
    return 0;
}
```

Will give:

```
     fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd 
     fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd 
     fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd 
     fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd 
     fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd 
     fksdpo gfdg fd gdf gdf gdf gfd gdf gd
```